# Which fires first MS Flow or Remote Event Recievers for custom list

Tags: sharepoint-online, remote-event-receiver, ms-flow

I have a custom list inside SharePoint online communication site. and for the custom list i have the following actions inside my remote event receiver:-

1)ItemAdded

2)ItemUpdated

I also have an MS flow which get fired when Item is Added or Updated.. so my question is about the sequence/order of the execution for the RER and the MS Flow? and is there a way to control it?

Answer (score 0):

Usually Workflow has sequence 1 and event receivers 10000. This was applicable for SharePoint On-Prem. For Online I'm no sure, but you can try it.

Comment: i am talking about MS Flow not MS workflow

Comment: I guess rules the same